# Does Apple reject apps build with Xcode 5? (13.10.2014)

Tags: xcode, ios7, ios8

I have to update an app build with Xcode 5 for iOS 7.

Unfortunately, there's not enough time and money to migrate it to iOS 8 by now.

Will Apple reject the app, when i'm trying to publish it to the AppStore?

Thank you!

Comment: Apple haven't made any announcement yet (Well not that I am aware) that says you have to use `xcode 6` to submit apps to the app store. All that you must do is make sure the app **DOES** work on iOS8 if it doesn't they will reject it. You can drop support for an earlier version but not the newest so it must run on iOS8. Be aware though that it will be coming soon if it has been made already that apps must be submitted using `xcode 6` and must be iOS8 ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your question, we submitted an application update built with xCode 5 recently, and it went through just fine.

Apple have previously sent an announcement to developers giving advance notice of any change in the minimum required xCode version.

On 13th Jan 2014, they announced that apps had to be built with xCode 5 and iOS 7 ready as of 1st Feb 2014. We can assume that they will follow a similar schedule for iOS 8 - if they actually fix all the bugs in it...

Answer (score 2):

If you mean Xcode 5.1.1, no they will not reject those apps. You can submit using Xcode 5.1.1 or higher. It says that in the binary section of iTunes Connect. I have used Xcode 5.1.1 to submit multiple apps. I archived in Xcode 6 then validated and submitted with Xcode 5.1.1 since validation/submission has been very buggy for me in Xcode 6.